# How to pass Different class to same ArrayList<> in constructor

Tags: java, android, arraylist, constructor

I have this code:

```
class A{
  String a1;
  String a2;
  getters / setters for a1, a2
}

public class B{
  String b1;
  getters/setters for b1
}
```

In another class C I am using this class for `ArrayList<A>`, `ArrayList<B>` and passing this ArrayList to a Class D constructor:

```
public class D {
  ArrayList<A or B> arraylist;

  public D(ArrayList<A or B> arraylist){
    this.arraylist = arraylist;
   }
 }
```

Now please help me how can i pass a pojo class to constructor `ArrayList<?>` of the type i require ? And please let me know the concept for this?

Comment: Use `ArrayList<Object> arraylist;`

Comment: i tried this using this makes getter() error

Comment: is your `arraylist` in D holds both A and B elements, or you have ArrayList which holds only A or only B elements?

Comment: Only A or B i clearly specified OR i am passing   case a:  
                    allViewAdapter = new AllViewAdapter(a,context);
                    break;
                case b:
                    playlistItems = dataProviderFromDataBase.getInterviewPlayListRecord(context);
                    allViewAdapter = new AllViewAdapter(b,context);
                    break;

Comment: if you hold only A or only B, you could make your D class generic ie `class D<T>{final List<T> list; public D(List<T> list){this.list = list;}} `

Comment: @user902383 exactly i tried same before posting question problem here is in calss D i cant access list.getSomevalue();

Comment: @Suhailkkhan you should be able to do `T value = list.get(x);`  what you want to do with your value inside class `D`?  any complex functionality could be injected via constructor.

Comment: @user902383 calss D is RecyclerView Adapter where in onBindViewHolder i need to access vales from ArrayList as arraylist.get(position).getSomeValue()    for example ArrayList<myclass> where my class sets and gets imageurls and text

Answer (score 1):

ArrayLists can only be constructed on a specific type (or a completely unspecific wildcard). "A or B" simply doesn't work.

But the concept you are looking for is called [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) ... in essence: do proper OO design. Because that typically helps with exactly such situations.

In your case: if you have classes that should provide the **same behavior**, then the best approach would be to define a certain interface, like

```
interface StringProvider {
  String getFirstValue(); 
  String getSecondValue();
```

with A and B implementing that interface; so that you then can write up:

```
ArrayList<StringProvider>
```

to then add either As or Bs, or even Objects of both classes into that list.

And hint: you even want to look into your design to understand why you need to different classes that are on the one hand so similar, but on the other hand worth having to different classes for them.

Comment: thanks can you make short example of this as i used above classes

Comment: i need different class because on same Adapter i am passing  different data from database

Comment: What do you mean by different data? Maybe you want to enhance your question in that regard and provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do `ArrayList<A or B>` - it's [violation of Java principles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html), since generalization of containers has to guaranty single interface for all contained objects.

You can do `ArrayList<SuperClass>` where `SuperClass` is abstraction either `interface` or `class` that is implemented/extended by both `A` and `B` classes.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options,

Option number 1 make A and B to share common interface.

Then you can define your class as

```
class D<T extends SharedInterface>{
  List<T> list;
 }
```

but, to do this, you need to change some of existing code, which is not always possible.

so here is option 2.
create converter interface

```
interface Converter<S,T> {
T convert(S source);
}
```

add Converter to your `D`

```
class D<T extends SharedInterface>{
      List<T> list;
      Converter<T,String> converter;
     }
```

now when you want to access your value you will do

```
converter.convert(list.get(position));
```

alternatively you could create abstract adapter, with methods which you require in class D, and create adapters for A and B. and then convert lists, and pass them to D.

Answer (score 0):

Class D:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class D{
  ArrayList<Object> arraylist;

 public D(ArrayList<Object> arraylist){
       this.arraylist = arraylist;
   }
 }
```

Class C:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class C {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList<Object>();
        A a = new A();
        a.setA1("Value a1");
        a.setA2("Value a2");
        B b = new B();
        b.setB1("Value b1");
        arr.add(a);
        arr.add(b);
        D d = new D(arr);
        for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++){
            if(arr.get(i) instanceof A){
                System.out.println("A:a1=" + ((A)arr.get(i)).getA1());
                System.out.println("A:a2=" + ((A)arr.get(i)).getA2());
            }else if(arr.get(i) instanceof B){
                System.out.println("B:b1=" + ((B)arr.get(i)).getB1());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
A:a1=Value a1
A:a2=Value a2
B:b1=Value b1
```

I think A and B should have another parent class, not superclass(object),if not,you'd better not put different class into the same list.